# How to add a field to array of subdocuments in all the documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection like below:-

```
{
   _id: 123,
   images: [{
     _id: ObjectId("213"),
     id: "1"
   }]
}
```

I want to add a field `imageResourceID` that is dependent on the `id` field.

```
{
   _id: 123,
   images: [{
     _id: ObjectId("213"),
     id: "1",
     imageResourceID: "1"
   }]
}
```

**What I tried?**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "images.imageResourceID": {
        "$map": {
        "input": "$otherImages",
        "as": "image",
        "in": "$$image.id"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

It adds `imageResourceID` field as an array containing `id` fields of all of the sub documents.
How can I make it to add `imageResourceID` field having value equal to the `id` field?

Thanks in advance. I am new to `MongoDB` so please bear with me.

Comment: Do you want to update in database or only retrieve the data like this?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I want to make an update I will use `$out` after I get the right result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over the `images` field using [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and need to specify each field inside the `in` expression of [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) aggregation and at last use [**`$out`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation to write them into another collection.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "images": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$images",
        "as": "image",
        "in": {
          "_id": "$$image._id"
          "id": "$$image.id",
          "imageResourceID": "$$image.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$out": "<output-collection>" }
])
```

Comment: Do I need to specify every field in the `in` expression? or is there a workaround for that?

Comment: yes you need to add every field inside the `in` expression

Comment: Thanks for your help! It worked like a charm. I did spend around 3-4 hours in it without success.